# Analysing the logical form of a statement where there's an $`if`$

Tags: logic

One of the statements in the exercise is:

> If someone who knows to love and is loved by someone,  then he feels
> the sun from both sides.

that I did not know exactly how to translate, especially the 'if' part.

**Glossary**:

> $L(x, y)$ = $x$ loves $y$
>
> $K(x)$ = $x$ knows how to love
>
> $S(x)$ = $x$ is very happy

This is the result of my attempt:

> $\exists x \in U ( K(x) \land (\exists y K(y) \land L(y, x))) \rightarrow S(x)$

My big problem is how to translate that beginning 'if'. Is what I did correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did good, but you don't need to add a clause assuming that $y$ **necessarily** knows how to love too. We just are informed that $x$ knows how to love and is loved by $y$ (who could be a jackass!).

Besides, since 'someone' in the context of the above sentence is arbitrary, we can take it as an universal quantification. Therefore we have:

> > $\forall x ((K(x) \wedge \exists y L(y,x)) \rightarrow S(x))$

PS: I assume there was a typo in your glossary above, when either $S(x)$ actually was supposed to mean 'x feel the sun from both sides' or the statement above should be stated as "If someone who knows to love and is loved by someone, then *he is happy*." Anyway, the logic form of the sentence remains the same.